# Why does Laravel b64-encode encrypted data?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I've noticed that data encrypted using the Laravel Crypt facade is taking substantially more memory than the original data, and looking at the source code of `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter` I saw that indeed the whole payload is base64-encoded before being returned by the `encrypt` function

My use case is to encrypt user files before storing them on the disk, and this leads to quite a big increase in the size each file takes.

I'm wondering why the data is b64-encoded and if it's really necessary? If not, what would be the simplest way to get an Encrypter that works the same way but without b64-encoding?

Comment: I think is to avoid encoding issues, but for sure you can temove this encoding.